# Regex line in js

Tags: javascript, regex

please help I have the regex line `^((?![<>=^@#]).)*$` which checking not ordinary symbols in an input field, it's ok but I need to add for this line one more condition , my line need to have vs.

For example when we have the name of sport game like this Patriots vs. Tigers

How can I complete my `^((?![<>=^@#]).)*$` condition and add rule for checking vs. in line (input field must have vs.) ?

It will be so cool if conditional also check spaces around vs. at left and at right, because for example Patriotsvs.Tigers is not good and need to show error also

Comment: Why not `/^\w+\s+vs\.\s+\w+$/`

Comment: If you want to complicate it further, try `^((?![<>=^@#]|\bvs\.\B).)*\bvs\.\B((?![<>=^@#]).)*$`.

Comment: What do you mean by "vs."?

Comment: Also, as others have alluded to, `(?![<>=^@#]).` is equivalent to `[^\r\n<>=^@#]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use look aheads with the start anchor to effectively use multiple conditions. Here is something that should work for you:

```
^(?=((?![<>=^@#]).)*$)(?=.*?\svs\.\s).*$
```

Will  match:

```
thing vs. another
Patriots vs. Tigers
```

Won't match:

```
th%^hg vs. another
thing another
thingvs.another
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is

```
/^[^<>=^@#]*?\bvs\.[^<>=^@#]*$/
```

which blacklists the characters `[<>=^@#]` and requires the literal text "`vs.`" somewhere in the string.

That character blacklist is probably insufficient if you're trying to only approve inputs that won't lead to SQL-injection or XSS.  Please consider using a stock input filtering/escaping system with this.

Comment: Nice, but "Patriots vs.Tigers" or "Patriots vs..." would match, which I'm not sure is expected.

Comment: Yeah.  You could try changing the second `*` to `+`, but I think this regex is already doing too much work.  Using two regex passes to separate filtering from parsing would address that, and emptiness would be best checked in the second.